# Change date format of a column in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've merged several excel files into single Dataframe. After some additional steps, I am saving it into single excel spreadsheet. There are two columns, that are saved as date in format:

3/8/2021  12:00:00 AM

How do I change the format of the date? I need to get it in format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' without time, or even better save it as a string as "YYYY-MM_DD"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['Date_column']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date_column'])
df['Date_column']=df['Date_column'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m_%d")
```

Comment: I am getting this error now:

to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing